# How to approach carrying out post-hoc analysis on a generalised mixed effects model with 3 fixed effects

Tags: r, mixed-models, posthoc

I am currently working on a generalized mixed effects model with 3 fixed effects and one random effect. Just as background, the random effect is the pond number (mesocosm), the response variable is the amount of chlorophyll-a (continuous data) and my fixed effects are two treatments: 1)nutrient enrichment and 2) WLF, both of which are binary yes/no type data. the third fixed effect is depth (0.1 meters and 0.8 meters) 
Anyway, I've created a glmer where all three fixed effects and the random effect have full interaction as follows:

```
GHQ<-glmer(CHa.t ~ Nutrients * WLF * depth * (1|mesocosm), family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = microalgae, nAGQ = 100)
```

A summary of this model shows that there is a significant interaction between nutrient enrichment, wlf **and** depth on Chlorophyll-a.

My question is how to carry out a post-hoc test when there are interactions between three fixed terms? 
I have tried `glht` and `ls_means` but both have resulted in an error.

here is the relevant data (sorry, I had to copy all of the rows for it to work):

> structure(list(mesocosm = structure(c(2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 15L,  15L,
>   18L, 18L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L,  8L, 8L, 9L,
>   9L, 14L, 14L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L,  7L, 7L, 11L, 11L,
>   13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 4L, 4L, 12L,  12L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 19L,
>   21L, 21L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L), .Label = c("1",  "2", "3", "4", "5",
>   "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",  "14", "15", "16", "17",
>   "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",  "25", "26", "27", "28"),
>   class = "factor"), Nutrients = structure(c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
>   .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
>       WLF = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), depth = c(0.1, 
>       0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 
>       0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 
>       0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 
>       0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 
>       0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8), Chl.a = c(3.301666667, 
>       4.026666667, 2.54, 3.936666667, 0.933333333, 1.67, 1.841666667, 
>       1.968333333, 1.493333333, 3.321666667, 2.78, 2.078333333, 
>       3.633333333, 2.621666667, 2.641666667, 4.991666667, 1.521666667, 
>       2.118333333, 3.061666667, 6.083333333, 2.343333333, 4.406666667, 
>       2.243333333, 3.03, 5.155, 3.723333333, 2.43, 2.06, 8.943333333, 
>       5.346666667, 6.161666667, 4.730833333, 7.336666667, 6.958333333, 
>       8.888333333, 1.898333333, 9.978333333, 7.951666667, 10.09333333, 
>       7.516666667, 10.62666667, 3.043333333, 4.621666667, 7.798333333, 
>       2.79, 7.926666667, 4.403333333, 3.85, 5.581666667, 8.18, 
>       2.795, 5.946666667, 4.093333333, 8.5, 7.356666667, 9.861666667
>       )), row.names = c(NA, 56L), class = "data.frame")

here are the packages I used:

```
if(!require(psych)){install.packages("car")}
if(!require(MASS)){install.packages("MASS")}
if(!require(rcompanion)){install.packages("rcompanion")}
if(!require(lme4)){install.packages("lme4")
if(!require(mlmRev)){install.packages("mlmRev")}
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}
if(!require(nlme)){install.packages("nlme")}
if(!require(agricolae)){install.packages("agricolae")}
if(!require(multcomp)){install.packages("multcomp")}
```

here is the chunk of code I used for the model:

```
CHa=microalgae$Chl.a
library("mlmRev")
GHQ<-glmer(CHa ~ Nutrients * WLF * depth * (1|mesocosm), family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = microalgae, nAGQ = 100)
summary(GHQ)
overdisp_fun(GHQ)
plot(GHQ)
qqnorm(resid(GHQ))
qqline(resid(GHQ))
```

here's my code for "ls_means" and the error that I got:

```
library(lmerTest)
ls_means(GHQ, pairwise~ depth*Nutrients*WLF, adjust="tukey")
```

> Error in UseMethod("ls_means") :    no applicable method for
>   'ls_means' applied to an object of class "c('glmerMod', 'merMod')"

I actually realise now that I don't really know how to use glht.

Comment: You can probably use the `emmeans` package. Then run something like `emmeans(CHQ, pairwise ~ Nutrients + WLF + depth)`, but note that you quickly get a lot of contrasts.

Comment: Are you seeking modeling advice? If so then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. If you are seeking programming advice then show your code with a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and state exactly what errors you are getting.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and your code for ghlt and ls_means.

Comment: thank you for your replies. I have edited the post to include the data I used and error I got.
Axeman, `emmeans(CHQ, pairwise ~ Nutrients + WLF + depth)` also gices an error saying "object 'CHQ' not found"